# Added a Signers email in the SendBehalfOf email but an error "This User lacks sufficient permissions. Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user"

Tags: docusignapi, electronic-signature

I have added an Signer's email in the SendBehalfOf using APIServiceSoapClient.
But an error "This User lacks sufficient permissions. Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user"
I am able to add user account's email for SendBehalfOf and it is working.

Our requirement is to add a Signer's email in the SendBehalfOf.
Can we add Signer's email in SendBehalfOf? If Yes please let me know how it will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about how to use SOBO on the DocuSign Dev Center?  Go to

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center

then go to **Explore** -> **Features** -> **SOBO** (Send on Behalf Of) functionality.

The page states the following:

A user, known as the authenticating user in this circumstance, that wants to authenticate for other users in the account must have the following DocuSign userSettings enabled for SOBO functionality:

```
+ apiAccountWideAccess
+ allowSendOnBehalfOf
```

Note: If you are setting user permissions through the DocuSign web console, these correspond to the **Account-Wide Rights** and **Send On Behalf Of Rights (API)** settings.  So you need to enable those account settings to use SOBO.